# Using contours in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, polygon, shapes, contour

I have a variety of contours, from which I need to draw masks. To do so, I need to use CV_FILLED when drawing the contours. However, my contours aren't closed - as in they aren't complete polygons, so the CV_FILLED thing won't work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can "close" my contours?

PS: For clarification, by closing I mean all segments aren't joined. Unlike a polygon, where the shape is closed off, mine is open.

Comment: What about making a convex hull? How accurate does the contour have to be?

Comment: Convex Hull doesn't provide a high enough level of accuracy. I need it to be exactly the same shape as the contour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to trying [convexHull](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexhull#cv2.convexHull), you can also look at trying the morphology operators [erode](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#void%20erode%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20element,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20iterations,%20int%20borderType,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue%29) and [dilate](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#void%20dilate%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20element,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20iterations,%20int%20borderType,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue%29). You can apply the erosion or dilation operators multiple times by using the `iterations` parameter.

Also, could you post the image with the objects you are trying to segment?

Comment: Using a convexHull doesn't provide the level of precision I require and using erode and dilate wouldn't work as the gaps are often very big. Even if I did use erode and dilate, it would effect the rest of my image, which I can't afford. 

I cannot post images of objects because my program will not be dealing with any specific object. Instead it would be dealing with hundreds of random polylines/polygons in different shapes and sizes. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create a mask of each contour, so I can work specifically on the pixels in the contour.

Comment: Can you post some sample code that you are using, and a specific case you are trying to solve. It will be helpful to me and others trying to assist you.